# Angular code mangled causes "Unknown Provider" message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, uglifyjs

I want to mangle my AngularJS file, and it works for almost the whole part. However, when I click through the app and navigate to the only part that uses [ngLazyBind](https://github.com/Ticore/ngLazyBind) and [angular-history](https://github.com/decipherinc/angular-history), I get the following issue: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- $lazyBind` .

I am using [ngMin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) in hopes that this kind of stuff wouldn't happen. When I set uglify's `mangled` property to `false`, this issue goes away.

Another little note - injecting `$lazyBind` into a controller is what causes the error. I can include `lazyBind` in the app without issue, but when I inject `$lazyBind` into a controller the error arises.

The reason I mention angular-history is if I completely eliminate lazyBind, the exact same error appears with `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: mProvider <- m <- History`.

Comment: Either you're using a minified version of angular or a minified version of your code. Either way, don't do it in development, or else you get these comprehensible errors.

Comment: It's not for development itself - I'm trying to get a working production prototype out.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the 2 libraries are minification-safe...

In [`angular-history`](https://github.com/decipherinc/angular-history/blob/master/history.js#L88) line 88...

```
angular.module('decipher.history', ['lazyBind']).service('History',
    function ($parse, $rootScope, $interpolate, $lazyBind, $timeout, $log,
```

From the error message, it looks like `$parse` was renamed to `m` and angular wasn't able to resolve it.

Same thing with [`ngLazyBind`](https://github.com/Ticore/ngLazyBind/blob/master/ngLazyBind.js#L89) line 89...

```
app.factory("$lazyBind", lazyBindProvider);
```

Comment: I agree - they don't look minification safe. However, I thought that ngMin was supposed to deal with it. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?